# How to configure a default JsonSerializerOptions (System.Text.Json) to be used by Azure Function v3?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, system.text.json

I have a set of Azure Functions v3 running on .net core 3.1.

I have a custom configuration of `JsonSerializerOptions` that I want to be used automatically by my functions when de/serializing data.

**Question**

How can I set up my Azure Functions so that they can use my default `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions` instance?

**Update 1**

Following the suggestion from @sellotape, I found out the following documentation regarding the `JsonResult` class:

[image: JsonResult documentation]

The problem is that my `JsonResult` instance does not have this property of type object ; it is only accepting a `JsonSerializerSettings` instance.

**Update 2**

I still get the following error and I am not sure where Newtonsoft is coming from:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson: Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'.
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5376#issuecomment-565568023) documents the same issue and apparently it's resolved in a fairly recent functions runtime release.

Comment: @sellotape Unfortunately this one was about JsonSerializerSettings when using Newtonsoft and JsonResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out [I missed a step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) when upgrading my Azure Functions from v2 to v3. To make it work, I had to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework to my `csproj`. Otherwise, my project kept referencing `JsonResult` from `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc.Core` v2.X.X which does not support `System.Text.Json`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- ADD THESE LINES -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then, I was able to specify my own `JsonSerializerOptions` instance like this:

```
return new JsonResult(<ContractClass>, NSJsonSerializerOptions.Default)
{
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
};
```

where `NSJsonSerializerOptions.Default` is a static instance of `JsonSerializerOptions`.

Answer (score 17):

It's not a perfect solution for those with existing Azure Function apps, but the [Azure Functions for .net 5 isolated runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) allows you to configure the JSON serialization options now. So for anyone starting new azure functions or have the budget and energy to upgrade existing ones, there's now first-class support for configuring the serializer exactly how you like it. It's unfortunate that enums have been second class citizens until just now, but better late than never.

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options => 
                    {
                        options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                        options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                    });
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pick System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json there you could configure either one like [seen in this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/ec518944144a4bccdc5ea1e0695d9d6b582bc084/samples/Configuration/Program.cs)

```cs
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Azure.Core.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace Configuration
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
                {
                    // Use any of the extension methods in WorkerConfigurationExtensions.
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }

    internal static class WorkerConfigurationExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Calling ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() configures the Functions Worker to use System.Text.Json for all JSON
        /// serialization and sets JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        /// This method uses DI to modify the JsonSerializerOptions. Call /api/HttpFunction to see the changes.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder ConfigureSystemTextJson(this IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(jsonSerializerOptions =>
            {
                jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                jsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                jsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;

                // override the default value
                jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
            });

            return builder;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The functions worker uses the Azure SDK's ObjectSerializer to abstract away all JSON serialization. This allows you to
        /// swap out the default System.Text.Json implementation for the Newtonsoft.Json implementation.
        /// To do so, add the Microsoft.Azure.Core.NewtonsoftJson nuget package and then update the WorkerOptions.Serializer property.
        /// This method updates the Serializer to use Newtonsoft.Json. Call /api/HttpFunction to see the changes.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder UseNewtonsoftJson(this IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure<WorkerOptions>(workerOptions =>
            {
                var settings = NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

                workerOptions.Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(settings);
            });

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice examples, very helpful and worked for me on .net 6 / functions v4

Comment: Actual link in in the main branch https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Configuration/Program.cs